# Update value in datatable

Tags: c#, asp.net, datatable

I was trying to update my datatable when ever the same book title is inserted into the cart.

```
public bool checkBook(DataTable dt, String title)
{
    bool returnval = false;
    try
    {

        foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
        {
            String checktitle = dr["Title"].ToString();
            if (title == checktitle)
            {
                int a = Convert.ToInt32(dr["quantity"].ToString());
                dr["quantity"] = a + 1;
                returnval = true;
            }

        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        //do something
    }
    return returnval;
}
```

Initial value in the quantity is 1, but when button was submitted, the quantity is still 1, but when it enter the third time, the number only started to increase by one. I don't understand where is the mistake?

Edited ::

```
protected void ListView1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    String title = ((Label)(ListView1.Items[ListView1.SelectedIndex].FindControl("Title"))).Text; ;
    decimal price = decimal.Parse(((Label)(ListView1.Items[ListView1.SelectedIndex].FindControl("Price"))).Text);

    cart cart = new cart(title, price);

    if (HttpContext.Current.Session["Cart"] != null)
    {
        DataTable shoppingcart = (DataTable)HttpContext.Current.Session["Cart"];
        bool check = checkBook(shoppingcart, title);
        if (check != true)
        {
            ShoppingCart.DataSource = cart.cartrow(shoppingcart);
            ShoppingCart.DataBind();
        }
        else
        {
            // if is true, it suppose to increase the quantity here 

            }

        }
    }

    else
    {

        HttpContext.Current.Session["Cart"] = cart.shoppingCart();
        ShoppingCart.DataSource = cart.shoppingCart();
        ShoppingCart.DataBind();
    }

}
```

class::

```
String title { get; set; }
decimal price { get; set; }
int quantity = 1;
DataTable CartTable;
DataRow tableRow;
public cart(String _title, decimal _price)
{
title = _title;
price = _price;
}
public DataTable shoppingCart()
{
CartTable = new DataTable("cart");

CartTable.Columns.Add("ID", typeof(Int32));
CartTable.Columns["ID"].AutoIncrement = true;
CartTable.Columns["ID"].AutoIncrementSeed = 1;

CartTable.Columns.Add("Title");
CartTable.Columns.Add("Price");
CartTable.Columns.Add("quantity");
CartTable.Columns["quantity"].DataType = typeof(Int32);

tableRow = CartTable.NewRow();
tableRow["Title"] = title;
tableRow["Price"] = price;
tableRow["quantity"] = quantity;
CartTable.Rows.Add(tableRow);
return CartTable;
}

public DataTable cartrow(DataTable _cart)
{

tableRow = _cart.NewRow();
tableRow["Title"] = title;
tableRow["Price"] = price;
tableRow["quantity"] = quantity;
_cart.Rows.Add(tableRow);
return _cart;

}
```

Comment: Your question is not clear. Please describe it more. where is `button`, what do you mean by button submitted?

Comment: Your question is not clear. Provide schema of your datatable. Provide the full code with your html markup.

Comment: I found a problem when i press the same book add-to-cart, it didn't add up the first time, but when i took the same url and open in other tab, it add up from one to two? is there any problem with my coding?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to show more of your code in order to determine what the problem is. Are you binding to the datatable? Are you recreating it after the button is clicked?

Anyway, the following is a little bit of code to show that updating works as you'd expect. Note the use of the generic Field extension method from System.Data.DataSetExtensions.

```
namespace StackOverflowTestCode
{
    using System.Data;
    using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;

    [TestClass]
    public class RandomTests
    {
        [TestMethod]
        public void DataTableUpdate_Test()
        {
            DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();
            dataTable.Columns.Add( "Title", typeof( string ) );
            dataTable.Columns.Add( "Quantity", typeof( int ) );

            dataTable.Rows.Add( "TitleOne", 0 );
            dataTable.Rows.Add( "TitleTwo", 0 );
            dataTable.Rows.Add( "TitleThree", 0 );

            DataRow[] rowsToUpdate = 
                dataTable.Select( "Title = 'TitleTwo'" );

            if( rowsToUpdate != null && rowsToUpdate.Length == 1 )
            {
                rowsToUpdate[ 0 ][ "Quantity" ] = 
                    rowsToUpdate[ 0 ].Field<int>( "Quantity" ) + 1;
            }

            // The right row was updated.
            Assert.AreEqual( 1, dataTable.Rows[ 1 ][ "Quantity" ] );

            // The other rows were not updated.
            Assert.AreEqual( 0, dataTable.Rows[ 0 ][ "Quantity" ] );
            Assert.AreEqual( 0, dataTable.Rows[ 2 ][ "Quantity" ] );
        }
    }
}
```

**edit**

After your update, the only thing that immediately jumps out at me as odd and a possible source of a bug is the following:

```
HttpContext.Current.Session["Cart"] = cart.shoppingCart(); 
ShoppingCart.DataSource = cart.shoppingCart();
```

Why are you calling that method twice?

Comment: the first is to bind the datatable to session, the other one was on the listview. is there any better way to do so?

Comment: @eugene You are just creating two variables to represent the same thing. Why don't you call the method once, setting a variable, and then set the session and the data source to that variable. Calling the method twice in a row is almost certainly at the least just unnecessary.

Comment: Thanks for the info, I'm still new in programming.

Comment: your code is working but the problem is, when i insert the book into the menu, it wouldn't update the quantity immediately, but after i refresh the page, it only increase the quantity. may i know what would be the cause of this problem?

Comment: @eugene No problem. You are doing fine. I would become very familiar with debugging. That is one of the easiest way to find and fix bugs.

Comment: @eugene are you calling the darabind method after inserting the book.